# Is my WordPress membership site considered SAAS?

Tags: wordpress, saas

I have simple WordPress site that accepts user registration and delivers online courses to organisations. The site works very similar to any other LMS platforms and is nothing really unique.

However, quite simply I want to know if my website (web application) is considered Software as a Service. Especially considering all users are registering to the same single installation of the site.

My initial thoughts tell me NO, its just a web app and at the very least it would only be considered SAAS if I was deploying single installations per customer.

I did some reading online and there seems to be some clear distinction between SAAS and Web Applications but I need some clarification.

**Update for clarity on the reason behind the question.**
We are eligible to offer the product to the local government. However, in order to fully eligible to the scheme, you must fall into the category of either SAAS, Cloud Services or Software Support. If we are considered SAAS then we can apply.

Comment: *"SAAS if I was deploying single installations per customer"* - Software As A **Service**, so anything that provides software as a service - not selling the software as product - can be considered one. an example would be Microsoft Office, their old model was the classic selling the software as product (through license keys) but nowadays Microsoft Office 365 is subscription based. even so, its opinion based though, people may have different definitions. *"WordPress site that accepts user registration and delivers online courses to organisations."* - ask yourself, are you renting the software?

Comment: Does it matter what it is considered? Is there a licensing concern or a tax accounting thing that's prompting the question, or just curiosity?

Comment: @ceejayoz Ive updated the question to clarify the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @BagusTesa I wouldnt say we aren't renting the software, just a subscription to the content.

Comment: @AlexKnopp though i said "renting the software," some people on the internet consider Netflix is an SaaS while some divided in regard to Youtube. the distinction mostly "opinion" and the divide between traditional stuff with SaaS and PaaS are thin and often are just marketing jargon. ceejayoz concern is on point, if you need a legal definition (e.g. for taxation), you should contact a lawyer and consult to local law.

Comment: @BagusTesa its not so much for legal, just figuring out what category the application fits into.